# Why firebase automatically closes my auth window? React - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making the login system for a web and when I want to login with Google or Facebook it's works normally but my window closes and I can't login the user into my web.

See my auth code:

```
handleGoogleAuth = () => {
    const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();

    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(googleProvider);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .getRedirectResult()
      .then(result => {
        //const user = result.user;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        alert(errorCode + ": " + errorMessage);
      });
  };
```

Or how can I open the login window in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your browser blocks third party cookies this will happen. It might happen when you are using incognito tabs, explicitly block them or if you have some third party browser extension.

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks. I'll close this because I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem lies in the fact that you are already logged in to Google or Facebook (or both). Try to do the same in the incognito window and see if it works as you expected.

Comment: Yes, really I'm at incognito mode. I want to do the login with redirect because with popups it's not work like I want in movile devices. I think that I need to open the auth in a new window but I don't know can I do